# Updating a complex object in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a 'complex' object similar to this in my MongoDB document:

```
{_id: "5zvYuC37aXSAjGNEg",
  profile: {
    name: "profile_name",
    keys:[{
      keyID: "12345",
      code: "12345",
      chars:[{
        name: "char_name1",
        char_id: "12345",
        active: 0
      }, {
        name: "char_name2",
        char_id: "67890",
        active: 0
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to update the value of `active` based on which `char_id` I pass to my query? Equivalent in MySQL would be probably something like:

`UPDATE sometable SET active = 1 WHERE char_id = 12345`

I tried to run this query:
`Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {char_id:char_id}, {$set:{active:1} });`
but after this, my object lost all values except `_id` and `char_id`.

Comment: You overwritten your data with your users update. It should looks like: `Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId(), char_id: char_id}, {$set: {active: 1}})`. In update method the second argument should be what you want to update and you have second argument as selector. Third should be callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how to write in meteor but below query should update in the mongo shell

```
db.Test.update({"profile.keys.chars.char_id":"12345"}, {$set: {"profile.keys.0.chars.$.active": "1"}})
```

Comment: not knowing his data, what if i have 7 rows with the same char_id. it updates the first one

Comment: correct if u chaNGE it to something like db.junk7.update({_id:"7zvYuC37aXSAjGNEg","profile.keys.chars.char_id":"12345"}, {$set: {"profile.keys.0.chars.$.active": "92"}})

Comment: I tried with Ajay's code and I got an error: `Uncaught Error: can't append to array using string field name [chars]`. Will try to play with Drew's code a bit, but I have to go out now so I'll give it a shot little bit later.

Comment: it definitely reshuffles things but the data seems intact

Comment: Hm, I tried few combinations and the closest I got was `Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId, 'profile.keys.chars.char_id':char_id}, {$set:{'profile.keys.0.chars.$.active': 1}});` but the wrong `char` is updated for some reason. Just to mention that every char will have its own unique `char_id`. I don't care if data is shuffled in some way since I will sort it later anyways :)

Comment: Uh, still not working for me... Will try to check it out little bit more later. Thanks for all the effort anyways!